# Program executes after for loop - C

Tags: c, loops

Here is my problem. Immediately after I type in some input and hit enter the program executes. And I some how figured out that the problem was due to the for loop which I was using. Here is the code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

main(){


 char myString[100]; 
 char myChar = myString[6];
 int i;

 for(i=0; i<=100; i++){
    scanf("%s", myString[i]);
 }

 printf("%c\n", myChar); 
 system("pause");

}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "type in some input and hit enter"?

Comment: You should really read a book about C before trying to write code.

Comment: My advice would be [Learn C the hard way](http://c.learncodethehardway.com/) which isn't actually as hard as it sounds. Anyway, good luck for your future C-coding!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are attempting to read 101 strings `%s`, but you allocated space for 100 characters. You pass a character instead of a character pointer to `scanf`, causing a crash.

If you are trying to read 100 characters, you should pass `%c` in the format line, **and** an address in the parameter part of `scanf` call:

```
scanf("%c", &myString[i]);
```

You should also either replace `<=` with `<`, or allocate `myString[101]`.

If you are looking to get one string, call `scanf` once, not in a loop:

```
scanf("%99s", myString); // myString is the same as &myString[0]
```

You are also reading the 6-th character before you place any data into the character array. That value is not going to change after the `for` loop.

Comment: He's even trying to read 101 strings.

Comment: then how do I get the string from the user ?

Comment: @Srivathsan you just `scanf("%s", myString);` without a loop

Comment: Kudos for helping, even though the question wasn't really stated nor expressed well.

Answer (score 2):

You are using the string format (`%s`), but passing a character `myString[i]`. That is not good.

Answer (score 0):

One problem could be your for loop:

```
for(i=0; i<=100; i++){
    scanf("%s", myString[i]);
 }
```

You have only 100 elements but accessing 101.

Regards
  Roger

Answer (score 0):

You should write:

```
 for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
 {
    scanf("%c", &myString[i]);
 }
```

Or:

```
scanf("%s", &myString);
```

btw, the line below:

```
char myChar = myString[6];
```

it should be placed after 'scanf' called, otherwise  mychar will always be 'c'